# How to better optimize my app?

Tags: performance, reactjs, optimization, google-chrome-devtools, rendering

### This is more of an open question

#### Short backstory:

I'm a Fullstack developer, currently in a close relationship with ***React*** :),
and I want to get as many good resources as possible about ***desktop/mobile web app optimization*** with ***NodeJS/React***

I ran into this amazing app which had an amazing complex infographic with so many possibilities, which made me understand how much I can improve my coding.

The developer who made it told me about some of the bugs they still have on the front end. So I figured I'm so unknowledgeable with performance issues, and this process best practices.

#### Goal:

I'm looking for resource beyond basic debugging tools.
I want to understand better how to use:

- Performance panel
- Audit panel
- How to optimize network requests
- How to optimize rendering animations
- Know about best practices for better loading my app
- and more...

#### P.S.

I'm not sure ***stackoverflow*** is the right place to ask this question, cuz I mostly see here questions with real right answer, and this is more of a *collection wanna be of best practices*.

### Collections:

**Here are some good collections I found**:

- https://github.com/stephanelebarque/awesome-performance
- https://github.com/davidsonfellipe/awesome-wpo
- http://jankfree.org/

Comment: There are lots of good official tutorials: [devtools/docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks).

Comment: **Here are some good collections I found**:

1.  https://github.com/stephanelebarque/awesome-performance
1.  https://github.com/davidsonfellipe/awesome-wpo
1.  http://jankfree.org/